# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; , SAMP MYSQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I get this error on my PHPMyAdmin

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to      

    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

[EDIT]
Sorry, I didn't put the full thing before, i've already had an BEGIN and an END, Look.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `accounts_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `accounts`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET new.RegiDate = now();
SET new.UpdateDate = now();
END;
```

This is the line ^^

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger is only one instruction, you don't need the `begin` keyword:

```
create trigger `accounts_insert` before insert on `accounts`
for each row
    set new.RegiDate = now();
```

If your trigger has multiple instructions, then you need to:

1. Change the default delimiter
2. Enclose the trigger instructions in a `begin...end` block
3. Restore the default delimiter

Example:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger `accounts_insert_2` before insert on `accounts`
for each row
begin
    set new.RegiDate = now();
    set @newRows = coalesce(@newRows, 0) + 1; -- Just a dummy example
end; &&
delimiter ;
```

**Why the `delimiter $$` and `delimiter ;`  are important?**

When you write a query, MySQL assumes that it ends where it finds the first standard "instruction terminator" (`;`). Since your trigger has more than one instruction, and every instruction must end with `;`, then MySQL assumes that the trigger definition is ended, and (of course) fails to execute it. So, what can be done? Simply redefine temporally the standard instruction terminator:

```
delimiter $$
```

Now, each instruction must end with `$$` to be executed. Define your trigger, and, when you want to end the definition, use your new temporary instruction terminator `$$`, and then redefine the terminator to the normal `;`:

```
delimiter ;
```

This *must* be done every time you define a multi insstruction trigger or a stored procedure or function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the full thing before, i've already had an BEGIN and an END, Look.



    CREATE TRIGGER `accounts_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `accounts`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.RegiDate = now();
    SET new.UpdateDate = now();
    END;

Comment: are you redefining the default delimiter? (`delimiter $$` before the trigger and `delimiter ;` after the trigger definition)?

Comment: No, I did not redefine it.

Comment: that's the reason for your error... I'll update my answer with an explanation